# how can I set the filesystem manager to pcmanfm?

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, pixel

I am using Raspbian Jessie, kernel 4.4, and the pixel Desktop.
when I try to set pcmanfm up as the file-system manager, the option in the "Customize" section of "Panel preferences" the selection stays blank.

How can I set pcmanfm to be my default package manager?

Comment: By default, the file manager is pcmanfm...did you change it and are trying to get it back?

Comment: I haven't used PIXEL but I doubt they wrote a new file manager as well, and since it is presumably mostly still LXDE, NULL's right, the fm would be pcmanfm.  Are you sure it *isn't*?

Comment: Its on the system for sure. when I try to use the directory applet, it says no file manager is configured. when I try to configure it, I can't.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Default file manager in `Default Applications for LXSession`. This can be found under `Preferences`, but you usually have to add it to the menu.

#### To add it to the menu:

1. Open `Preferences > Main Menu Editor`.
2. Click on `Preferences` on the sidebar to the left and check the box next to `Default Applications for LXSession`.

#### To setup default File Manager

3. Open `Preferences > Default Applications for LXSession`.
4. Under `File Manager`, select `PCManFm`.

NOTE: You will only ever need to do steps 1 and 2 once.